# CodeIgniter Cannot modify header information

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi Currently Im still Learning CodeIgniter. Im trying to use its session and enabled the session in autoload file

First the file structure of files is like this/

I structure my files like this. all templates will go in views/index.php

my problem is I get this error  `Cannot modify header information`

I have a controller Home

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Home extends CI_Controller{  

        public function index()
        {     
            $view['title'] = 'Welcome';

            $data['data'] = $view;
            $data['content'] = 'home';
            $this->load->view('index',$data);
        }

    }
```

My views is something like this

**views/index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
    <?php     
        //echo ("Welcome User: " . $datas["user_id"]); 
        $this->load->view('header',$data);
        $this->load->view('template/' . $content);
        $this->load->view('footer',$data);
    ?>
</html>
```

**views/header.php**

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content=""> 
    <title><?=$title?></title>  
      <link href="<?=ASSETS_PATH?>css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="<?=ASSETS_PATH?>css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">  
  </head> 
  <body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

**views/footer.php**

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=ASSETS_PATH?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=ASSETS_PATH?>js/javascript.js"></script> 
  </body>
```

then my content

**views/template/home.php**

```
<div class="jumbotron mod-jumbotron"> 
    <div class="jm-button" style="text-align:center;">
           <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

I don't know why do i get that error session. Please hope you could help me.
I didn't even set a session. I have just added it in auto load and don't know why i get that header problem. Is my file structure wrong?

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at site/application/controllers/home.php:2)
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 675

Comment: What is `ASSETS_PATH` ? Use `base_url()`

Comment: oh. its `define('ASSETS_PATH','http://localhost/site/assets/');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a space before the opening `<?php` tag in your Home controller which is causing output.

```
// a space here is enough to cause output
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

Comment: ooh God What have I done..well you where right Mudshark. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line on your config file or autoload file or add in index.php file may be resolved your problem.

```
ob_start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put the loading of the pages in the controller and not in the views.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller{  

    public function index()
    {     
        $data['title'] = 'Welcome';
        $this->load->view('header',$data);
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer',$data);
    }

}
```

The view is for display, and you control it using the controller.

```
<script src="<?= base_url(). 'js/javascript.js' ?>"></script> 
<link href="<?=base_url(). 'css/custom.css'?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: well. thanks about the base_url(). I tried editing my site but still i get the error

Comment: Remove the session from autoload and try again. It is probably the session that is causing the error.

Comment: yup. when i add the session it cause the error. But I need the session library.

Comment: Add the encryption key in the config.php. In CI, sessions are store in tables so you will need to create a table in your database to save the sessions